# Ideals containing $\langle h,y \rangle \subset \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, with $h \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ separable

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $h \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ be [separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_polynomial) of degree $d \geq 2$,
in other words, there exist
distinct $c_1,\ldots,c_d \in \mathbb{C}$
such that $h=(x-c_1)\cdots(x-c_d)$.

Let $I:=\langle h,y \rangle \subset \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, be the ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ generated by $h$ and $y$.
$I$ is a radical ideal and a finite intersection of the $d$ maximal ideals $\{\langle x-c_i,y \rangle\}_{1 \leq i \leq d}$.

**Claim:** There exist a finite number of ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ containing $I$;
the list is $\langle g,y \rangle$,
where $g | h$.

For example, if $d=3$ and $c_1=\alpha, c_2=\beta, c_3=\gamma$,
then the following ideals are containing $I= \langle (x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma),y\rangle$:
$\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, $\langle x-\alpha, y\rangle$, $\langle x-\beta, y\rangle$, $\langle x-\gamma, y\rangle$, $\langle (x-\alpha)(x-\beta),y \rangle$, $\langle (x-\alpha)(x-\gamma), y\rangle$,$\langle (x-\beta)(x-\gamma), y\rangle$, $I$.

> **Question:** Is my claim true? Am I missing something?

**Remarks:**

**(1)** I have used the assumption that $h$ is separable, so, for example,
$\langle (x-\alpha)(x-\beta),x-\gamma,y \rangle$ becomes $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, because
$(x-\alpha)(x-\beta),x-\gamma$ generate $1$, see [this](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09GW).

Notice that, $\langle (x-\alpha)(x-\beta),(x-\alpha)(x-\gamma),y \rangle$ is actually $\langle x-\alpha, y \rangle$ which is already listed above;
indeed, there exist $U,V \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ such that $U(x-\beta)+V(x-\gamma)=1$,
hence, $U(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)+V(x-\alpha)(x-\gamma)=(x-\alpha)[U(x-\beta)+V(x-\gamma)]=x-\alpha$.

**(2)** Of course, we can replace the generators of the ideals in the list,
for example, instead of $\langle x-\alpha,y \rangle$,
we can write $\langle (x-\alpha)+y^5,y \rangle$.

**(3)** Is it just because $I= \cap_{i=1}^{d} \langle x-c_i,y \rangle$ and
such an intersection is contained only in partial intersections.
Indeed, Let $\mathbb{C}[x,y] \supsetneq J \supseteq I$, $J$ arbitrary proper ideal containing $I$.
There exists a maximal ideal $M$ of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ containing $J$:
$M \supseteq J \supseteq I$, so, $M \supseteq I= \prod_{i=1}^{d} \langle x-c_i,y \rangle$.
Therefore, $M = \langle x-c_j,y \rangle$, for some $1 \leq j \leq d$.

**(4)** Related question: [i](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4399584/generators-of-a-finite-intersection-of-maximal-ideals) and [ii](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814693/what-are-the-maximal-ideals-containing-the-intersection-of-maximal-ideals).

Any comments are welcome, thank you!

Comment: Why are you bothering with making this detailed a post about something that is so obviously true? And separability is not needed. Any ideal of the form $(p(x),q(y))\subset k[x,y]$ with neither $p$ nor $q$ constant will give you the same result.

Comment: @HankScorpio, thank you for your comment. I agree with you.. just wished to be 100% sure that I am not missing something.